# couchdb, get last 10 documents

Tags: couchdb

Using mysql this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I do this in couchdb for all documents with "type":"message"? (without pulling all documents with type:message)

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by **last**? latest or oldest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a view that emits all doc ids. The view keys will be used for sorting automatically.

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.type && doc.type === 'message'){
        emit(doc._id, null);
    }
}
```

Then execute a query: http://host/yourdb/_design/yourdesigndoc/_view/viewname?limit=10&include_docs=true&descending=true

Because you want the full document, we didn't included anything as value in the view. Instead, we add `include_docs=true` to fetch every full document for the view entries.

Note that there is also a builtin view that does the same: http://host/yourdb/_all_docs?limit=10&include_docs=true&descending=true

PS: You should be aware of the fact that CouchDB by default uses UUIDs as IDs, which will render the sorting more or less useless, if you really want to get the latest docs. Either provide your own incremental IDs (what about distribution/replication?) or use a new field that stores the time the doc has been created and use in the view as well.

---

If your docs have a `created` field (i.e. UNIX timestamp, JavaScript Date.now() or even a RFC 3339-like string), you can build an index on these values.

Here is the time-based view:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.type && doc.type === 'message' && doc.created){
        emit(doc.created, null);
    }
}
```

Note that we will not emit the doc._id itself. However, CouchDB stores the `doc._id` where the data came from for each emitted key/value pair automatically, so we can again use  `include_docs=true` to fetch the complete docs.

Query http://host/yourdb/_design/yourdesigndoc/_view/viewname?limit=10&include_docs=true&descending=true

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, doing this will return the 10 oldest documents containing type:message. I need the 10 newest documents. The only way I can think of doing this is to pull every doc id, taking the last 10 ids from that result set, then calling the documents directly with the ids...It just doesn't feel like its the correct way to do it.

Comment: Have you read my PS? It depends on how your doc._ids are generated/assigned. Perhaps you must switch to `descending=false`or even add a field generated to your docs and use it.

Comment: wow no it doesnt, I swear I must have tried that 100 times haha...no idea where I messed it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the IDs of your documents are already incremental, instead of the default UUIDs of CouchDB, you do not even need to define a view, you can just use the default **_all_docs** view, e.g.

```
http://couchdb_host/your_db/_all_docs?limit=10&descending=true&include_docs=true
```